# Как с помощью Selenium обойти защиту CloudFlare

Tags: python, selenium, cloudflare

Всем доброго дня. Подскажите пожалуйста как можно обойти защиту CloudFlare.
Пытался с помощью библиотеки undetected-chromedriver, не помогло. Нашел в сети следующий код, однако тоже не помогло:

```
import os
import time
from platform import system

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

options = Options()
# options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")

exec_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'driver', 'chromedriver.exe') if system() == "Windows" else \
    os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'driver', 'chromedriver')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=Service(log_path=os.devnull, executable_path=exec_path))

driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", {
    'source': '''
        delete window.cdc_adoQpoasnfa76pfcZLmcfl_Array;
        delete window.cdc_adoQpoasnfa76pfcZLmcfl_Promise;
        delete window.cdc_adoQpoasnfa76pfcZLmcfl_Symbol;
  '''
})

driver.get('https://nowsecure.nl')
time.sleep(20)
driver.close()
driver.quit()
```